# return a variable from a event listener

Tags: javascript

I have a generic function for XMLHttpRequests. as follows:

```
function XMLRequest(address, data){
    this.html = "null";
    this.xml = null;
    this.stat = null;
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(this) {

        console.log("from event listener, this.html = "+this.html);
        this.ready = req.readyState;
        if(req.readyState == 4)
        {
            this.stat = req.readyState;
            if(req.status == 200)
            {
                try{
                    this.xml = req.responseXML.documentElement;
                }
                catch(err){
                    this.xml = err;
                }

                try{
                    this.html = req.responseText;
                }catch(err){
                    this.html = err;
                }
                console.log("html = "+this.html);
            }
        }   
    }, false);

    req.open("GET", address+"?"+data, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('content-type', "text/xml");
    req.send();    
    return this;

};
```

I made it with the idea that i would use the  `watch()` function to watch for a change in in `this.html` or `this.xml`. However, I never saw the change, and I realized why;

Inside of the anonymous listener function, this refers  to the anonymous function, not `XMLRequest`

I was hoping to find a way around this, to somehow get the xml & text response out of the listener function and into the `this.xml` & `this.html` of the `XMLRequest` function, so that I can then watch for it

Is there any way I can do that?

--edit--

Brad's example, with my edits, for discussion:

```
function MyObject(){
    this.publicFoo = 'BAR';
    var privateFoo = 'bar';

    var self = this; // store current context so we can reference it in other scopes.
    this.CallMe = function(){
        self.publicFoo = 'newBAR';
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert('public: ' + self.publicFoo + '\nprivate: ' + privateFoo);
        },100);
    };

    return this;
};

var myobj = MyObject();
myobj.CallMe();
alert(myobj.publicFoo)  <-- I want this to alert "newBAR", not "BAR"
```

Comment: BTW, I know only firefox supports `obj.watch()`, but I found code right here on stackoverflow that someone wrote to add that function to all browsers

Comment: Sorry for last comment, i realized you probably want them public after the fact. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the variables you need before using them, then reference them (as you'd typically do to avoid scope problems:

```
function MyObject(){
    this.publicFoo = 'BAR';
    var privateFoo = 'bar';

    this.CallMe = function(){
        // set them as something referenceable when not within the object's scope
        var iSee_publicFoo = this.publicFoo,
            iSee_privateFoo = privateFoo;

        setTimeout(function(){
            alert('public: ' + iSee_publicFoo + '\nprivate: ' + iSee_privateFoo);
        },100);
    };

    return this;
};

var myobj = MyObject();
myobj.CallMe();
```

---

Using the `var self = this` version:

```
function MyObject(){
    this.publicFoo = 'BAR';
    var privateFoo = 'bar';

    var self = this; // store current context so we can reference it in other scopes.
    this.CallMe = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert('public: ' + self.publicFoo + '\nprivate: ' + privateFoo);
        },100);
    };

    return this;
};

var myobj = MyObject();
myobj.CallMe();
```

Comment: that example works as expected, but in my example at `console.log("from event listener, this.html = "+this.html)`, that shows that this.html is undefined, not "null" as I want it too

Comment: Also, I did change `function(this) {` to `function() {`. I just had that there to see what it did.

Comment: @AsherMaximum: before the event listener use `var thishtml = this.html;` Then, inside the listener, use the `thishtml`. Does that work as desired? You have to remember `this.` has a different context within the function.

Comment: @AsherMaximum: Also, what you'll typically find is people use `var self = this;` then reference "self" in place of the main object's "this". Since `this` is a keyword, it's always going to reference current scope.

Comment: Yes, that works to get the value inside the function. But the problem is that I need to change `this.html` based on what happens inside the listener, so that I can `watch()` for that change when I create an instance of the object

Comment: Please see my edits of your self reference example. I put it in my original question. I think you'll see what I am trying to do then.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't understand you example on this page, and missed the jsfiddle example. Yes, the self reference seems to work like I need